# How to select 0.000 but not 0 in R?

Tags: r, select, statistics, p-value

I have a vector of p-values, some of them are 0.000, and some of them are 0. How do I select 0.000, but not 0 because exact 0 doesn't make sense to me. I tried the code below, but it regards 0.000 and 0 as the same value. Any hint or respons will be appreciated. Thanks.

```
p = c(0,0,0.000,0.000,0,0,0.001)
select = p[p ==0.000 & p!= 0]
```

Comment: `0` and `0.000`are identical (`identical(0, 0.000) # [1] TRUE` ) What are the actual values in your `p` vector,  i.e. what's the output of `dput(p)` ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, margusl. dput(p) returns the actual p values? I'll try it. Also, does p-value = 0 have any statistic significance? What do you think?

Comment: Function `near` might also be helpful.

Comment: This is effectively (eventually?) the same as https://stackoverflow.com/q/9508518/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/3358272, and [R FAQ 7.31](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f). It all stems from how computers deal with "arbitrary precision numbers", see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754.

Comment: When I'm looking for something that is _really close to_ but not the same as some number, and I need to guard against floating-point precision problems like the previous links, I often use something like `abs(x - somenum) < 1e-9`, where `x` is your number (`p`, perhaps), `somenum` in your case is `0` but can be other numbers, `1e-9` is close enough to zero unless you know you have high precision numbers, and `<` can be interpreted here as "effectively zero" ... use `>` for "effectively not zero".

Comment: Timon, the links I provided should inform the background of why `c(0, 0.000)` is not giving you two different values. However, it does not really solve your problem. For that, however, if `p[p > 0]` does not resolve your issue, then it would be incredibly useful to see the "real" values in `p` that you're seeing as a result if your tests; for that, please [edit] your question, paste the output from `dput(p)` into the code block, and then please @-ping me and we'll sort through what is missing. Hope this helps!